# Query not show any records if one column on table has no data

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query returns 0 rows if a value is not present on `paymatic_debtors_info` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       prj$quote_sections.quote_section_id,
       cl$invoices.invoice_id,
       cl$invoices.invoice_no,
       cl$invoices.total Invoiced,
       paymatic_debtors_info.amount Paid
FROM   cl$invoices
       INNER JOIN cl$Invoice_items
       ON cl$Invoice_items.invoice_id = cl$invoices.invoice_id
       INNER JOIN paymatic_debtors_info
       ON paymatic_debtors_info.REF = cl$invoices.invoice_no
       inner join VW_PM_INV_BAL
       on VW_PM_INV_BAL.INVOICE_NO = paymatic_debtors_info.REF
       INNER JOIN prj$quote_items
       ON rj$quote_items.quote_item_id=cl$Invoice_items.quote_item_id
       INNER JOIN prj$quote_sections
       ON prj$quote_sections.quote_id    = prj$quote_items.quote_id
       AND prj$quote_sections.quote_section_id = '1000015948'
       and paymatic_debtors_info.TYPE = 'Pmt'
       or paymatic_debtors_info.TYPE = 'Crd'
```

I have tried union queries, if statements - same result.

Expected Results:

```
Quote_Section_id Invoice_id Invoice_no Invoiced Paid
1000065052       7290012356 325698     3530
```

Comment: Unable to read to message, but the answer is left outer join.

Comment: Nope - Got too many rows

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Sorry I have adding screenshots before so I wont do it in future

Answer (score 2):

Without some sample data to replicate the problem it is a bit difficult to answer but this might give a solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       qs.quote_section_id,
       i.invoice_id,
       i.invoice_no,
       i.total Invoiced,
       pdi.amount Paid
FROM   cl$invoices i
       INNER JOIN cl$Invoice_items ii
       ON ( ii.invoice_id = i.invoice_id )
       INNER JOIN prj$quote_items qi
       ON ( qi.quote_item_id = ii.quote_item_id )
       INNER JOIN prj$quote_sections qs
       ON ( qs.quote_id    = qi.quote_id )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT pdi.REF,
                pdi.Amount
         FROM   paymatic_debtors_info pdi
                INNER JOIN VW_PM_INV_BAL ib
                ON ( ib.INVOICE_NO = pdi.REF )
         WHERE  pdi.TYPE IN ( 'Pmt', 'Crd' )
       ) pdi
       ON ( pdi.REF = i.invoice_no )
WHERE  qs.quote_section_id = '1000015948'
```

Comment: Hi - I am get an error on the last pdi.ref saying invalid identifier - but it is there - I have even used full names

Comment: @user3602012 Updated - added the missing alias to the 3rd line from the bottom.